# Can the distribution over the squared moduli of the 'probabilities' defined by an RBM with complex weights be written as an RBM with real weights?

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning

Given a matrix of connection weights $W$ (and bias vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$), a [restricted Boltzmann machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine) generates a probability distribution over a discrete set of inputs $\vec{v} = \{v_1, \dots, v_N\}$ by
$$
p(\vec{v}) = \sum_{h_1, \dots h_M} \exp(\sum_{j}^{N}a_j v_j + \sum_{i}^{M}b_i h_i + \sum_{i j}W_{i j}h_i v_j)
$$

Here, $v_i$ and $h_i$ can take the values $+1$ or $-1$.

For my application, $p(\vec{v})$ can be complex, so the RBM is defined with complex network weights $W_{i j}$ (idem. bias vectors). Of course, $p(\vec{v})$ can no longer be interpreted as probability distribution.

I would like to know if, given a complex-valued RBM, I can write the distribution over the squared moduli $|p(\vec{v})|^2$ as an RBM with real weights. I know it should be possible, given that an RBM can approximate any probability distribution, but can it be done *efficiently*?

The new hidden units of this RBM do not necessarily have to take the values +1 or -1, or even be binary-valued.

**What I tried**

The complex-valued RBM has the alternate form
$$
p(\vec{v}) = \exp(\sum_{j}^{N}a_j v_j)\prod_{i}^{M}\sum_{h_i}\exp(h_i(b_i + \sum_j W_{i j} v_j))
$$

The objective is to find a similar form for $p(\vec{v})p(\vec{v})^{*}$, with real weight matrix $V$, and real bias vectors $A$ and $B$. It is quickly seen that
$$
A_i = a_j + a_j^{*}
$$

If I write out the RBM-form of $|p(\vec{v})|^2$, forgetting about the bias vector $A$, I get
$$
|p(\vec{v})|^2 = \prod_{i}^{M}\sum_{h_i, h_i'}\exp(h_i(b_i + \alpha_i) + h_i'(b_i^{*} + \alpha_i^{*}))
$$
where
$$
\alpha_i = \sum_j^N W_{i j} v_j
$$
I am looking for an efficient representation
$$
|p(\vec{v})|^2 = \prod_{i}^{M'}\sum_{H_i}\exp(H_i(B_i + \sum_j^N V_{i j} v_j))
$$
with $B_i$, $V_{i j}$ real, where $H_i$ does not have to be binary-valued, and the number of new hidden units $M'$ can be different from $M$.

How can I start to solve this? Help is very much appreciated.